# How do I selected a table row based on a dynamically added class name?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a table where I select a row by clicking it.
On click, the class `selected` is added to the row.

Here is the code:

```
  // Change row background color on click
  jQuery('#rowList tr').live("click", function() {
    jQuery(this).closest("tr").siblings().removeClass("selected");
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });
```

Now, clicking another button, I need to get the title of the selected row.
For testing, I'm trying to retrieve the entire row.

```
  jQuery('#fileBrowser input.addImage').live("click", function() {
    var tmp = jQuery("#rowList tr:selected").html();
    alert(tmp);
  });
```

But all I get is `null`. I'm guessing this is because the added class is not bound. I thought `live` kept track of dynamically added content, but I guess not.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
var tmp = jQuery("#rowList tr.selected").html();
```

You need to select the row by class using `.selected`, which uses the [`class-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) instead of the [`selected-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/), which only targets `<option>` elements that are selected.